# Reading every other line from a txt file and saving into an array

Tags: java, arrays

assignment:
A school that your little cousin attends is selling cookies.  If your cousin's class sells more cookies than any other class, the teacher has promised to take the whole class on a picnic.  Of course, your cousin volunteered you to keep track of all the sales and determine the winner.

Each class is identified by the teacher's name.  Each sales slip has the teacher's name and the number of boxes sold.  You decide to create two parallel arrays:  one to hold the teacher's names  and one to record the number of boxes sold.  Here is a sample of the data:

The first number gives the number of classes, and then a teacher's Name is followed by the number of boxes sold
15 
Smith
3
Courtney
... so on so forth

My main issue (because i can just duplicate it for the "to-be" parrallel array)
is getting every other line to save into an array for the boxes sold
so array "boxSold" 
would look like 
[1] 15 
[2] 3

```
    package assignment5Package;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    import java.io.*;



    public class assignment5Demo 
    {

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //create arrays, variables
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
                (new FileReader ("/Users/lee/Desktop/class/cs 113/Assignment5/cookies.txt"));

            System.out.println("How many sale slips are there");

            int numSaleSlips = keyboard.nextInt();
            int[] soldBox = new int[numSaleSlips];
            //______String[] teacherName = new String[numSaleSlips];
            int soldBoxIndex;
            int teacherNameIndex;
            //String soldBoxString; (line 50)




            //initializing both strings to 0 and "_"
            for (soldBoxIndex = 0; soldBoxIndex < numSaleSlips; soldBoxIndex++)
            {
                soldBox[soldBoxIndex] = 0;
            }

            //**for (teacherNameIndex = 0; teacherNameIndex < numSaleSlips; teacherNameIndex++)
            //**{
            //**    teacherName[teacherNameIndex] = "_";
            //**}

            //reading from the cookies.txt file
            for (soldBoxIndex = 0; soldBoxIndex < numSaleSlips; soldBoxIndex++)
            {
                if (soldBoxIndex % 2 != 0
                {
                    String soldBoxString;


                    soldBoxString = input.readLine(); //reads in value and assigns/re-assigns
                    soldBox[numSaleSlips] = (int) Double.parseDouble(soldBoxString); //type-casted to fit variable type, converts to double, stores in array
                    System.out.println(soldBox[soldBoxIndex]);
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Error at " + soldBoxIndex +".");
                }

            }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be a quick-and-dirty solution, but will get the job done:

```
for (soldBoxIndex = 0; soldBoxIndex < numSaleSlips; soldBoxIndex++)
{
    if (soldBoxIndex % 2 != 0
    {
        String soldBoxString;


        soldBoxString = input.readLine(); //reads in value and assigns/re-assigns
        soldBox[numSaleSlips] = (int) Double.parseDouble(soldBoxString); //type-casted to fit variable type, converts to double, stores in array
        System.out.println(soldBox[soldBoxIndex]);
    }
    else 
    {
        input.readLine(); //read the following line, but ignore its content, effectivly skipping the line
    }

}
```

You might also need to work the numbers of the for-loop a bit, to accomodate the skipped line.

Comment: THANKS for the concept :D
i took the "reads the following line and ignores its content idea"
and just made a simple for loop